# How to make sure specific parameters are passed to the method?

Tags: java, android

For example, there is a method `public void set_gender(String gender) {}`, make sure only `"male"` or `"female"` is passed to this method **without using enumeration**.

Also, how to meet this demand when the method declaration is `public void set_gender(String... params) {}`?

If there's no such way to realize this, how could I give a warning in IDE when someone is passing a string that this method could not understand, just like how it works in Android Studio when I'm passing a value that is not a flag that defined inside a certain Class.

Comment: `public static final String MALE = "male"` or much better use boolean `public static final boolean MALE = true` and `public static final boolean FEMALE = false` any issues with this method?

Comment: make `setGender` a private function and create two new methods `setMale` and `setFemale` which will call `setGender`, BUT an enum would be better - why not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are 4 ways I could think of:

1. Use pre-defined method without parameter:

   ```
       public void setMale() { /* TODO: Implement */ }

       public void setFemale() { /* TODO: Implement */ }
   ```
2. Keep `setGender()` but use `boolean` values as its parameter instead of plain `String`. `true` means it's male, `false` female (or the other way around):

   ```
       public void setGender(boolean male) { /* TODO: Implement */ }
   ```
3. Keep `setGender()` while using `String` as its parameter, and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the supplied parameter does not comply with the scope:

   ```
       public void setGender(String gender) {
          if (!"male".equalsIgnoreCase(gender) && !"female".equalsIgnoreCase(gender)) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad parameter");
          }
          /* TODO: Implement */ 
       }
   ```
4. Just use enums which, frankly, was designed with this exact use cases in mind. Or [`IntDef`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) if you're really that worried about performance.

Oh, and as an addition, this question you asked:

> If there's no such way to realize this, how could I give a warning in
>   IDE when someone is passing a string that this method could not
>   understand, just like how it works in Android Studio when I'm passing
>   a value that is not a flag that defined inside a certain Class.

They achieve this by using `IntDef`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is [StringDef](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef.html) annotation for such cases. You can mark parameter with it and then check it in runtime to verify.